# Can I use braces to fix squeaky floors?

Tags: framing, brackets, squeak

I have quite a few squeaky floors in my 6-month-old house. The main floor plywood (glued and nailed) got rained on as it was being assembled. My basement is unfinished. I would like to do some repairs from below. I'm thinking that I can find a brace as pictured below (or 1000 of them) and screw them in to address the problem? Sound like a good plan?

[image]

Comment: I think that you have a problem because the wood got wet and now it is drying. Fixing it with the braces wouldn't solve the problem. Yes the squeaky sound will stop but the wood will continue to "breath" and it is possible that it can even brake on some places. I would leave it for some time (6 months, a year) and then then varnish it. But be aware floor must be dry first!

Comment: 6-month old house that squeaks - "builder callback" is the phrase you are looking for.